# rxjs created observable timeout always errors

Tags: timeout, rxjs, rxjs5

ok, so now I'm really puzzled. Executing the following code

```
const created = Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
  observer.next(42)
})
const ofd = Rx.Observable.of(42)

const createSub = name => [
  val => console.log(`${name} received ${val}`),
  error => console.log(`${name} threw ${error.constructor.name}`)
]

created
  .timeout(100)
  .subscribe(
    ...createSub('created')
  )

ofd
  .timeout(100)
  .subscribe(
    ...createSub('ofd')
  )
```

Prints

```
"created received 42"
"ofd received 42"
"created threw TimeoutError"
```

I don't understand this at all, why does the `created` Observable error even though it emits a value but the `ofd` Observable does not??

Using RxJS 5, problem occurs with 5.0.3 in jsbin.com and 5.4.3 in my app.

(Note: This happens with subjects too, which led me to create this example)

Comment: can you share jsbin code?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/fihotoduqo/1/edit?js,console

it's the same code as above though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Observable.of` is completing the stream right after the value has been emitted.

`Observable.create` keeps the observable opened. And that's why the `timeout` is throwing an error.

Replace

```
const created = Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
  observer.next(42)
})
```

By

```
const created = Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
  observer.next(42);
  observer.complete();
})
```

and there's no error anymore.

Comment: that actually makes sense... but it is not what the docs of timeout say:
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timeout.html

the error should not be thrown if any value is emitted, or am I reading this wrong?

Comment: "The Timeout operator allows you to abort an Observable with an onError termination if that Observable fails to emit any items during a specified span of time", you emit a value, then there's a timeout. I guess it's normal behavior

Comment: had to read that twice, so it errors because after the first value the timeout occurs... hmmm, I guess the way to go is to make sure the observable completes. Is there no "timeout to first emit"?

Comment: @DanielPotensky I've been thinking about the "timeout to first emit" but can you please open another question for that and let me know here? It's not really related to initial problem, is it?

Comment: Full answer all prepared :)

Comment: thanks a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46886073/rxjs-timeout-to-first-value